# Java application deploy in oracle weblogic server

Tags: java, jar, build.gradle, weblogic12c

I have created a gradle project, and build it to get a jar file, which I placed in window server. Created a .bat file to execute the .jar, and with help of windows task scheduler I scheduled it as required.

This works fine, but in server has many scripts scheduled which causes to slow the work and many other issue.

I have a oracle weblogic server where a WAR file is hosted.

My question is can I host the Java application/jar file and automate it there. I tried but normal jar file is not read by weblogic.

Can anyone guide me instead of this how can I make the application, so that I can deploy it in weblogic server and host it.

My project contains mostly .java class files, and one properties and one xml for log.
WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0 and its not a localhost, I create in Eclipse Oxygen and deploy there.

Currently the jar file is hosted in windows server and used task scheduler to run it.

If any reference to read or watch or follow will also be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not pretty sure what is you goal... to host a JAR File on an JEE Server. Thats not the Ordinary job of an JEE Server..
You Can put Classes like JAR in the DOMAIN_DIR/classpath folder and at the folder to the classpath. In this case you can reach the JAR by your deployed EAR/WAR Application.

I have done a new File into the "/bin" folder "setUserOverrides.sh" and put

> CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/classpath
>
> export CLASSPATH

in it.
This files can be edited by Tasks or Sourcecontrol ... but im not sure if you need to restart the Server after edeting the files...

greets Jens